# Guided waves $E_z$ and $B_z$

Tags: electromagnetism, waveguide

In Griffiths’ *Electrodynamics*, fourth edition, p.427, we have $$E_x = \frac{i}{(\omega/c)^2 - k^2} \left(k\frac{\partial E_z }{\partial x}+ \omega \frac{\partial B_z}{ \partial y}\right), $$

$$E_y = \frac{i}{(\omega/c)^2 - k^2} \left(k\frac{\partial E_z }{\partial y}- \omega \frac{\partial B_z}{ \partial x}\right). $$

Griffiths says to insert those equations into the Maxwell equation $$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 0.$$

Doing this I have $$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} = 0$$

$$= E_z\left[\frac{ik}{(w/c)^2 -k^2} k \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{ik}{(w/c)^2 -k^2}\omega \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}\right].$$

What am I doing wrong?

According to Griffiths, I should have

$$= E_z\left[\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2 }+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + (\omega/c)^2 -k^2\right]$$

Comment: Remember that the divergence also acts on the $z$ component of $\mathbf{E}$; you only have the contribution from $\partial_x E_x + \partial_y E_y$

Comment: @ZadeJohnston Griffith say that I have to use $E_x$ and $E_y$ to find $E_z$

Comment: yes, you're trying to find a differential equation for $E_z$, the $z$-component of $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}_0$ (Eq. 9.178). But the electric field I was meaning is $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}=\tilde{\mathbf{E}}_0 \exp[i(kz-\omega t)]$ (Eq. 9.176); you need to use $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=0$ on this vector. If there's still any confusion, let me know and I can try give a better explaination in an answer.

Comment: What are those two “equations” without left-hand-sides supposed to mean? And what are the bare derivatives in them operating on?

Comment: @ZadeJohnston I was thinking about that. Even if I have $E(x,y,z) = (E_x + E_y + E_z) e^{i(kz- \omega t)}$, thus
$\frac{\partial E_z }{ \partial z} = \frac{\partial E_z }{ \partial z} e^{...} + E_z ik$

Comment: @happypaticle you're on the right track, remember that $E_z$ is only a function of $x$ and $y$ so the first term disappears

Comment: Ah, I see, Thank you!